# C++ code to class diagram

Tags: c++, class-diagram

Is there is a way I can generate a hierachial class diagram from C++ code. My code is spread over 5 to 6 .cpp files.

I would like to know if there is any free tool for the same.

Regards,
AJ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's e.g. doxygen

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/features.html says:

> Uses the dot tool of the Graphviz tool kit to generate include dependency graphs, collaboration diagrams, call graphs, directory structure graphs, and graphical class hierarchy graphs.

It creates graphs like

[image]
(from http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/structvtkKdTree_1_1__cellList.html, an example listed on the doxygen site)

Since the question was about class diagrams you might also be interested in the [UML_LOOK](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_uml_look) flag that makes the ouput a bit more uml-like.

Comment: Let's not confuse class diagram with inheritance diagram,which is exactly what doxygen does and nothing more.A class diagram contains not only the connections between the various classes involved but also their internal structure - members, functions and methods. What you have shown in your post is misleading omho and should not be considered the correct answer unleass dependency diagram is what the author of the question meant,in which case the question should be altered accordingly.Even at the beginning of your answer where you cite doxygen's documentation it does NOT mention class diagrams.

Comment: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_uml_look makes it a bit more uml...ish

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the useful information. Should add this in your comment instead of the link that lists doxygen's features.

Comment: @rbaleksandar : no no, your critique is valid by all means, +1 for the comment. Though I like doxygen a lot I don't believe it's the best tool for this particular job (if taking the question at face value). But I do believe it is a good tool when working your way up from already written code to the missing design documents and documentation. And that's what the question sounded to me ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Class diagrams are networks, not hierarchies. There a re quite  a few tools that can generate them - my favourite is [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/), but it isn't free (there is a trial).

Answer (score 3):

[Umberello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) is the Linux application that generate diagram from code.

Comment: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/umbrello/umbrello/umbrello.pdf states, that Umbrello does not generate any kind of diagram from code.

Comment: Umbrello doesn't generate diagrams from code. It only imports classes: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/umbrello/umbrello/code-import.html

Answer (score 0):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can [create class-diagrams](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html). However, I believe these diagrams are only to show the network of classes, they do not list methods and members and such.