# Create a class diagram without using doxygen

Tags: iphone, c++

Is there a way to create a class diagram without using doxygen?

Comment: You have a few options - there are a few good/similar questions in the **Related** section to the right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UML free reverse engineering tool for C++ (.h/.cpp ==> Class Diagram)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015471/uml-free-reverse-engineering-tool-for-c-h-cpp-class-diagram)

Comment: also similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591025/c-code-to-class-diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can obviously create class diagrams and any other UML diagrams by means of any UML editor. There are many available, for instance Papyrus is provided in the latest Eclipse Modeling distribution. Otherwise TopCased is a very good one (http://www.topcased.org).